# Getting java.io.InterruptedIOException with OkHttp 4.5.0 randomly

Tags: java, sockets, okhttp, http2

I am getting these following interrupted exeptions randomly from okhttp on a post calls using http2. I even have my read/write and call timeouts set to 0 meaning no timeouts as per the documentation.

This is my httpclient below

```
        this.client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .protocols(Collections.singletonList(Protocol.H2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE)
            .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT))
            .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(20, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .callTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
```

Can anyone advise why i am getting these following exceptions and how to possibly fix these

```
    java.io.InterruptedIOException: null
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.waitForIo$okhttp(Http2Stream.kt:662) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.kt:140) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.kt:96) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:106) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:79) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:82) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:197) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:148) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.lb.http.EnvoyHttp2Proxy.executeRequest(EnvoyHttp2Proxy.java:117) [common-code-lb-2.1.0.1365.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.lb.http.EnvoyHttp2Proxy.execute(EnvoyHttp2Proxy.java:83) [common-code-lb-2.1.0.1365.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.lb.http.mycomHttpTracingClient.callClient(mycomHttpTracingClient.java:111) [common-code-lb-2.1.0.1365.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.lb.http.mycomHttpTracingClient.execute(mycomHttpTracingClient.java:92) [common-code-lb-2.1.0.1365.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.lb.http.mycomHttpTracingClient.execute(mycomHttpTracingClient.java:55) [common-code-lb-2.1.0.1365.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.lb.http.mycomHttpClientWrapper.execute(mycomHttpClientWrapper.java:43) [common-code-lb-2.1.0.1365.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService.getBulkserviceCs(serviceCService.java:264) [serviceB-common-code.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$aae0540b.CGLIB$getBulkserviceCs$6(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$aae0540b$$FastClassByGuice$$c4d006de.invoke(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.$MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.utils.logging.profiler.ProfilerInterceptor.executeBlocking(ProfilerInterceptor.java:111) [common-code-mycom-stats-2.1.0.1360.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.utils.logging.profiler.ProfilerInterceptor.invoke(ProfilerInterceptor.java:103) [common-code-mycom-stats-2.1.0.1360.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:55) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$aae0540b.getBulkserviceCs(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService.getAllBulkserviceCs(serviceCService.java:233) [serviceB-common-code.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService.getserviceCs(serviceCService.java:147) [serviceB-common-code.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$aae0540b.CGLIB$getserviceCs$1(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$aae0540b$$FastClassByGuice$$c4d006de.invoke(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.$MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.utils.logging.profiler.ProfilerInterceptor.executeBlocking(ProfilerInterceptor.java:111) [common-code-mycom-stats-2.1.0.1360.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.utils.logging.profiler.ProfilerInterceptor.invoke(ProfilerInterceptor.java:103) [common-code-mycom-stats-2.1.0.1360.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:55) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$aae0540b.getserviceCs(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService.getserviceCs(serviceCService.java:130) [serviceB-common-code.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$aae0540b.CGLIB$getserviceCs$0(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$aae0540b$$FastClassByGuice$$c4d006de.invoke(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.$MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.utils.logging.profiler.ProfilerInterceptor.executeBlocking(ProfilerInterceptor.java:111) [common-code-mycom-stats-2.1.0.1360.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.utils.logging.profiler.ProfilerInterceptor.invoke(ProfilerInterceptor.java:103) [common-code-mycom-stats-2.1.0.1360.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:55) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$aae0540b.getserviceCs(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.BookmarkEnricherService.enrich(BookmarkEnricherService.java:54) [serviceB-common-code.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.BookmarkEnricherService$$EnhancerByGuice$$647c6025.CGLIB$enrich$0(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.BookmarkEnricherService$$EnhancerByGuice$$647c6025$$FastClassByGuice$$b13fc520.invoke(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.$MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.utils.logging.profiler.ProfilerInterceptor.executeBlocking(ProfilerInterceptor.java:111) [common-code-mycom-stats-2.1.0.1360.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.utils.logging.profiler.ProfilerInterceptor.invoke(ProfilerInterceptor.java:103) [common-code-mycom-stats-2.1.0.1360.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:55) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.BookmarkEnricherService$$EnhancerByGuice$$647c6025.enrich(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.redis.RedisDataMigrationService.migrateHashValues(RedisDataMigrationService.java:21) [serviceB-common-code.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.redis.RedisBookmarkmycomIdManager.lambda$enrich$10(RedisBookmarkmycomIdManager.java:191) [serviceB-common-code.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.common-code.HystrixProxy.run(HystrixProxy.java:29) [serviceB-common-code.jar:?]
at com.mycom2.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302) [hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
at com.mycom2.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298) [hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at com.mycom2.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56) [hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
at com.mycom2.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:47) [hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
at com.mycom2.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:69) [hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

and

```
java.io.InterruptedIOException: interrupted
at okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.kt:98) ~[okio-2.5.0.jar:?]
at okio.OutputStreamSink.write(JvmOkio.kt:50) ~[okio-2.5.0.jar:?]
at okio.AsyncTimeout$sink$1.write(AsyncTimeout.kt:103) ~[okio-2.5.0.jar:?]
at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.kt:247) ~[okio-2.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Writer.flush(Http2Writer.kt:120) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection.flush(Http2Connection.kt:408) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSink.close(Http2Stream.kt:626) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okio.ForwardingSink.close(ForwardingSink.kt:37) ~[okio-2.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange$RequestBodySink.close(Exchange.kt:242) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okio.RealBufferedSink.close(RealBufferedSink.kt:268) ~[okio-2.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:60) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:82) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:197) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:148) ~[okhttp-4.5.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.lb.http.EnvoyHttp2Proxy.executeRequest(EnvoyHttp2Proxy.java:121) [common-code-lb-2.1.0.1366.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.lb.http.EnvoyHttp2Proxy.execute(EnvoyHttp2Proxy.java:87) [common-code-lb-2.1.0.1366.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.lb.http.mycomHttpTracingClient.callClient(mycomHttpTracingClient.java:111) [common-code-lb-2.1.0.1366.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.lb.http.mycomHttpTracingClient.execute(mycomHttpTracingClient.java:92) [common-code-lb-2.1.0.1366.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.lb.http.mycomHttpTracingClient.execute(mycomHttpTracingClient.java:55) [common-code-lb-2.1.0.1366.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.lb.http.mycomHttpClientWrapper.execute(mycomHttpClientWrapper.java:43) [common-code-lb-2.1.0.1366.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService.getBulkserviceCs(serviceCService.java:264) [serviceB-common-code.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$af924afb.CGLIB$getBulkserviceCs$4(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$af924afb$$FastClassByGuice$$82565de9.invoke(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.$MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.utils.logging.profiler.ProfilerInterceptor.executeBlocking(ProfilerInterceptor.java:111) [common-code-mycom-stats-2.1.0.1360.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.utils.logging.profiler.ProfilerInterceptor.invoke(ProfilerInterceptor.java:103) [common-code-mycom-stats-2.1.0.1360.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:55) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$af924afb.getBulkserviceCs(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService.getAllBulkserviceCs(serviceCService.java:233) [serviceB-common-code.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService.getserviceCs(serviceCService.java:147) [serviceB-common-code.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$af924afb.CGLIB$getserviceCs$1(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$af924afb$$FastClassByGuice$$82565de9.invoke(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.$MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.utils.logging.profiler.ProfilerInterceptor.executeBlocking(ProfilerInterceptor.java:111) [common-code-mycom-stats-2.1.0.1360.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.utils.logging.profiler.ProfilerInterceptor.invoke(ProfilerInterceptor.java:103) [common-code-mycom-stats-2.1.0.1360.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:55) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$af924afb.getserviceCs(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService.getserviceCs(serviceCService.java:130) [serviceB-common-code.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$af924afb.CGLIB$getserviceCs$0(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$af924afb$$FastClassByGuice$$82565de9.invoke(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.$MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.utils.logging.profiler.ProfilerInterceptor.executeBlocking(ProfilerInterceptor.java:111) [common-code-mycom-stats-2.1.0.1360.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.utils.logging.profiler.ProfilerInterceptor.invoke(ProfilerInterceptor.java:103) [common-code-mycom-stats-2.1.0.1360.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:55) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.serviceCService$$EnhancerByGuice$$af924afb.getserviceCs(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.BookmarkEnricherService.enrich(BookmarkEnricherService.java:54) [serviceB-common-code.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.BookmarkEnricherService$$EnhancerByGuice$$aafb80a9.CGLIB$enrich$1(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.BookmarkEnricherService$$EnhancerByGuice$$aafb80a9$$FastClassByGuice$$c0b15525.invoke(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.$MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.utils.logging.profiler.ProfilerInterceptor.executeBlocking(ProfilerInterceptor.java:111) [common-code-mycom-stats-2.1.0.1360.jar:?]
at com.mycom.common-code.utils.logging.profiler.ProfilerInterceptor.invoke(ProfilerInterceptor.java:103) [common-code-mycom-stats-2.1.0.1360.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:55) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.service.BookmarkEnricherService$$EnhancerByGuice$$aafb80a9.enrich(<generated>) [guice-4.0.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.redis.RedisDataMigrationService.migrateHashValues(RedisDataMigrationService.java:21) [serviceB-common-code.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.backend.redis.RedisBookmarkmycomIdManager.lambda$enrich$10(RedisBookmarkmycomIdManager.java:191) [serviceB-common-code.jar:?]
at com.mycom.serviceB.common-code.HystrixProxy.run(HystrixProxy.java:29) [serviceB-common-code.jar:?]
at com.mycom2.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302) [hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
at com.mycom2.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298) [hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at com.mycom2.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56) [hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
at com.mycom2.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:47) [hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
at com.mycom2.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:69) [hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get this if you're canceling futures. Unfortunately your stacktrace is incomplete so I can't confirm that as a likely cause.

Comment: We not cancelling futures in the remainig strace from what I see. Are you suggesting that these requests are being cancelled by us instead ?

Comment: I can post the rest of the trace but not sure if that will be useful

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks Jesse, I updated the post above with the entire stacktrace

Comment: This code is executing inside a future. You should check if that future is being canceled, possibly implicitly by unsubscribing an observable.

Comment: Seems like we were cancelling the request in hystrix due to timeouts. thanks